# I can print date and time but ser.write to USB serial LCD 16*2 will not work

Tags: python

I have an LCD 16*2 display that has a Midas USB board connected. My program is part of a lighting and temperature control for an Aquarium. The following code will display the required date and time on screen but causes errors when ser.write is used to try to display the (now) variable. I'm new to Python so would appreciate any help.

```
import usb.core
import usb.util
import os
import datetime
import time

import serial

def getdatetime(timedateformat='complete'):
from datetime import datetime
timedateformat = timedateformat.lower()

timedateformat == ('complete')
str(datetime.now())


print(' ')

b=bytearray(1)                

now = datetime.datetime.now()

getdatetime('complete')

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600)

time.sleep(0.5)


print(now)

dt = list(time.localtime())
hour = dt[3]
minute = dt[4]
second = dt[5]


print(hour)
print(minute)
print(now)


while 1:


    dt = list(time.localtime())
    hour = dt[3]
    minute = dt[4]
    second = dt[5]
    ser.write(now)
    os.system('clear')


   time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: "causes errors" - which errors? Please include the full traceback in your question and also format your code.

Comment: @ForceBru we must read thoughts :)

Comment: Sorry for lack of info. The problem is the ser.write(now) or any other ser.write variable. I have found that this runs fine in Python 2 but gives an incorrect string format error in Python 3. As i am new to Python i am looking for a simple explanation as to what is required to modify the code. Thanks for looking.